# Resize image using imagick

Tags: php, image-resizing, imagick

I'm trying to convert a PDF file with multiple pages into different JPGs. I'm using the code above:

```
$pdf_in = 'file.pdf';

$img_array = array();
$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution(144,144);
$im->readImage($pdf_in);
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(85);
$num_pages = $im->getnumberimages();
$i = 0;

for($x = 1;$x <= $num_pages; $x++) {
    $im->setiteratorindex($i);
    $im->thumbnailImage(990,0);
    $im->setimageformat('jpeg');
    $im->writeImage("page".$x.".jpg");
    $i++;
}

$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

The conversion goes fine, all the JPGs are created as expected. However, a core.xxxx file is created only when I use the thumbnailImage() Function.

EDIT: all generated JPG must have 990px ​​width. So I'm using the thumbnailImage() function to do this. But when I use this function, a core.xxxx file is generated with size of 200mb or more each time I run the script, filling all the space I have on disk in a few days. If I comment out the line $ im- > thumbnailImage (990,0), the core file is not generated, but the JPGs will not have the right width. The problem is: why is being generated this file, Is there a way to avoid this? Can I resize the images in another way?

I'm using imagick ver 6.7.2-7 2015-07-23 with cpanel

Can someone please explain what is going wrong?

PS: I don't want to use the exec function because it will take a lot of CPU and RAM usage.

Comment: "a core.xxxx file is created only when I use the thumbnailImage()" The word core is not in the code. So apparently the problem you are having isn't related to the code you posted. Please can you clarify what problem you are having.

Comment: Danack all generated JPG must have 990px ​​width. So I'm using the thumbnailImage() function to do this. But when I use this function, a a core file is generated with size of 200mb or more, filling all the space I have on disk in a few days. If I comment out the line $ im- > thumbnailImage (990,0), the core file is not generated, but the JPGs will not have the right width. The problem is: why is being generated this file, Is there a way to avoid this? Can I resize the images in another way? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Your question is still really hard to understand.... Do you mean that there is a temp file being left over that is not being deleted?

Comment: Exactly Danack. Every time I run the script, a huge core.#### files are being deposited into the directory where the script resides, and consumes a lot of disk space. I want to avoid or automatically delete these core files. It seems that core dump only occurs when a program crashes, but all the JPG are being generated correctly. Thanks for your help , and if you need I can explain again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. Instead of using

```
$im->thumbnailImage(990,0);
```

I used

```
$im->scaleImage(990,0);
```

and it worked. The core files are no longer created. I also tried the function resizeImage() before, but it was the same problem. Thank you Danack for your attention. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving temp files around is either a bug in the version of ImageMagick you have installed or a result of the application crashing in the middle of execution.

I think you will need to clean those files up either manually or through a regular task to do so. e.g. http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15960